# count output of full outer joins many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, rdbms

How can I make full outer join for many tables like ex: Curreny_1,Current_2 .. Curreny_5 and count the total output of all?
Remark: Many tables not only two tables.
EX:Main Table "Currency" has id,Name,c1,c2 as single values.
Currency_1 has nick name, address as multi values, currency_3,currency_4 --etc have multi values for the same id in the main table "Curreny".
I want to make full outer joins for all not only 2 tables.

Comment: Add table definitions, sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.)

Comment: you can add multiple sub query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html

Comment: please edit your question and set tag only for RDBMS you're using. Then post some examples what you want to obtain.